# Keep communication with database mysql when the browser closed by user

Tags: mysql, linux, php

I currently need help comrades here. I'm making application development based on php, the application is quesionaire system, which the system have countdown timer for 60 minutes when user already start(click start button).
So far I could pushes to timer to the database when the user is in the session login, I update database per second. and the current system is when user logout the countdown timer will stop, example user logout when countdown in 30 minutes. So when user login back still get 30 minutes.

But my client would not like it. My client want if user already click start button so count down timer will go on until 60 minutes even though the user has not logout until 60 minutes or user close the browser untill 60 minutes.

So my question how to implement it? What I must do when user click button start?
I want to when user click button start will push count down timer to database mysql, altough user close the browser count down always push to database.

Structure database table is:

```
- id (int) auto_increment;
- user_id (int);
- residual_time (int); <--I push it per second, so per second will update it until 0.
```

My server using linux ubuntu server. And I is owner in the server.

Thank you.

Comment: Just save the start time once, and calculate the difference from the current time for display. No need to do the countdown inside the database.

Comment: Hello @JoachimIsaksson thanks for reply, but if it is not counted down and saved to the database system can not know user which ones are up to 60 minutes.

Comment: When a user clicks start, save the time. At any time later when you need to know how much time is left, just take the current time and subtract the start time, if the difference is more than an hour, ,his time is up. What I meant is that you only need to save the start time _once_, not count down every second in the database.

Comment: Hello @JoachimIsaksson, if not every second, how if the power failure so computer/laptop user would die.

Answer (score 0):

I would do exactly what @Joachim suggested and follow this flow:

- Replace `residual_time` with `start_time` with type being datetime.
- Add `last_update` with type being datetime.
- When the user clicks start set the `start_time` and `last_update` with the `NOW()` MySQL function
- Write a function and run it with AJAX every 30? second to check if `last_update` is 60 minutes past `start_time` and if so to stop the questionnaire and clear both `start_time` and `last_update`.

Now let's assume a user quits and logs out mid time alloted and then logs back in to continue:

```
//sudo code example
//check if start_time is set
if(isset(start_time)){
    //check if last_update time is set
    if(isset(last_update)){
        //calculate the time difference in minutes from previous start_time and last_update time
        time_diff = last_update - start_time;
        //if time difference is less than alloted time example 60 minutes
        if(time_diff < 60 minutes){
            //update start_time with current time less time difference for already used time
            start_time = NOW() - time_diff minutes
        //if time difference is greater than the allotted time
        } else {
            //kill the page with the time expired message
            die(Your time has expired);
        }
    //if last_update time is not set
    } else {
        //set start_time to NOW()
        start_time = NOW();
    }
//if start_time is not set
} else {
    //set start_time to NOW()
    start_time = NOW();
}
```

Comment: I would be careful not to update the time every second and only update every 15-30 seconds unless timeout to the second is MANDATORY as this will put an extra load on your server. We had a chat script set to update every three seconds and you would be surprised how much fast the server ran when we changed it to every 15 seconds.